# GCM Phonegap, how to send a message to the handset's core notifications

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I have successfully set up the code to run GCM over phonegap on an android app. I have managed to secure the handset registration ID and able to send a message to the app using this ID in a PHP script.

My only problem is that the message displays as a javascript alert whilst the app is open, and I am looking to have message sent to the handset's core notifications (similar to what's app) while the app is or isn't running.

Does anyone know if the GCM plugin for Phonegap is capable of doing this?

Comment: Did you come right with this problem?

Comment: could you point me to a place where I can learn to do that? I need to implement push notification in my Phonegap Android app

Answer (score 0):

Mark Nutter has a fork of the Android C2DM Phonegap plugin, converted to use GCM.

https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

Look at the onMessage method in GCM-Cordova/src/com/cordova/gcm/GCMIntentService.java it's a good place for StatusBarNotifications.

And look at the onReceive method in 
GCM-Cordova/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBroadcastReceiver.java, which is a good place for Toast pop-ups.

Comment: ive used marks gcm plugin and received the notification. i what to combine it with the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification to display the notification in the status bar. what i wonder is will this work when application is not running? also, is there a plugin to cover receiving to notification?

Answer (score 0):

Mark's plugin works great, though I am having trouble getting it to work while the app is not running. Its a known bug.

Please keep in mind the plugin does not do system notifications. It just pushes data to your phone...this is awesome as it lets you do whatever you want with this data, and can be used to push system notifications with some native code on top.

The big problem Im having as well, however is getting it to work when application is offline. :(

Comment: is there a solution for android phonegap for push that can work offline.

Comment: The GCM plugin works offline. Its limitation is that is only a push notification rather than a system notification. I solved this by commenting out the javascript, that sends the notification through phonegap, and instead send the data to a custom receiver I created myself which creates a system notification.  Unfortunatelly what I'm saying is it required some native code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different plug in to get the status bar notification find it at:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification

Then in the on receive function in the gcm java script on the device just add this line of code:

window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Put your title here", "Put your message here");

Works just fine only problem is how to wake the device... I'll post an answer to that soon as I find it.

I found a way to wake the device sorry I forgot to post the reply sooner:

The trick was to create a pending intent in the GCM Service's reciever module in the JAVA code the pending intent is then received by the application's main activity, the activity and the activity is loaded into ram. the GCM service then waits five seconds so that the main activity is done loading... and then recives the notification and sends it to cordova... works for me but you may also want to check if the activity is already running before you raise the pending intent.

The code for the GCM service is added below

```
//Intent notifyIntent = new Intent("com.cordova2.gcm.MainActivity");

Context context2 = getApplicationContext();

  PendingIntent pendingIntent;
  Intent notifyIntent = new Intent();
  notifyIntent.setClass(context2, com.cordova2.gcm.MainActivity.class);
  pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(context2, 0, notifyIntent, 0);
  try {
    pendingIntent.send();
} catch (CanceledException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}



long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*1000;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This article makes it all happen...

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/android-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html

On the step entitled 'Status bar notification' I chose to use java native code rather than the javascript plugin.